# What does 'AnyReactComponent' do?

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

I started work with [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react) and found this line:

```
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>
```

What does it do?

Comment: That's a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components).

Comment: Close-voters: how is this "off topic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a stateless functional component (that is, the function is a `render` function, taking `props` as argument). The functionality could be rewritten like this:

```
class AnyReactComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
       const { text } = this.props;

       return <div>{text}</div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is this stateless func component used for? if it doesnt render anything and hasnt any other method inside. 

Just to **clarify, for example**, if in an imaginary function we have `let array = []`, then we know it used later as a interjacent array to store some temporary data and perform some actions on it. Otherwise that array is unused and must be removed from code

Comment: i understood my question in the upper comment, so the answer: __stateless function component__ are used to be a component without any method, just render. **For example** we need in an imaginary network a profile page, so **an avatar** may be there a separate stateless component that **needed to be rendered** and nothing more